# Checkbox click event on table row click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal

I have a table that contains several rows each containing one checknox. Checkbox will get selected on the row click event. 
Now how can I apply an `onclick` event for a checkbox?

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {      
  countPopChecked();           
});
```

This is my script. This is working when I click on the checkbox. But I want this functionality when I am clicking on the table row.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').closest('tr').on('click', function() {      
    countPopChecked();           
});
```

or :

```
$('tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {      
    countPopChecked();           
});
```

Comment: this is not working for me.. Giving $('input[type="checkbox"]').closest('tr').on is not a function

Comment: @praji - your version of jQuery is way to old, update to 1.9.1, or at least something above 1.7 to make on() work.